# How use datas in same column

Tags: php, mysql

Screenshot mysql: 
[image]

If I want to use the data in column “sender name” or "subject" then i use code

```
include ("connect.php");
$model = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entries WHERE entries_id='3' limit 1"); 
$profil = mysql_fetch_array($model);

echo $profil[sender_name]; 
echo $profil[subject];
```

but how to use other data that users enter and are located in the column “data”?

for example 
in the column “data” there are fields City, Address, Phone,…

What code to use to insert just name of the city (in example: Berlin) ?

Comment: your screenshot it's too small to read, you need to put another one or explain yourself better

Comment: I cant attach... Link: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9zitL.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The value in the data column is serialized. To use it you must first unserialize it [(see php.net - unserialize)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

For example (using your logic, I'm pretty sure you don't need the limit part of this query.)

```
include ("connect.php");
$model = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entries WHERE entries_id='3' limit 1"); 
$profile = mysql_fetch_array($model);
$data = unserialize($profile['data']);  //This is now an array of the data
```

To see what the unserialized data looks like you can then do this

```
print_r($data);
```

And to use the unserialized data to get, say the value, you would do

```
echo $data[0]['value']; //This will print "Berlin" for entries_id = 3.
```

Comment: Now i get this:

Array
(
 [0]=>Aray
  (
   [id]=>1
   [slug]=>city
   [name]=>City
   [type]=>text
   [options]=>
   [parent_id]=>0
   [vaule]=>Berlin
  )....... How do I print vaule on the page?

Comment: try now :) this is why saving stuff in a serialized format is something I strongly discourage ...

Comment: In testing code, i can see BERLIN, but wen open .php page, nothing is displayed.

Comment: Erik, i PrtScn: http://www.balkanselection.com/test.jpg  
When i click test, and on web page.